# simple dynamical system with disturbance

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

I am new here and trying to simulate a very simple dynamical system with periodic force or Dirac function:

$$mx'' + bx' + kx = u(t)$$

I want to draw the displacement(position) and velocity of the system.

Any suggestion for start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [`DSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html) and [`DSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolveValue.html) function for this. In case of $m$, $b$ and $k$ constant it can be easily solved:

```
DSolveValue[m x''[t] + b x'[t] + k x[t] == DiracDelta[t], x[t], t]
(* E^(1/2 (-(b/m) - Sqrt[b^2 - 4 k m]/m) t) C[1] + 
    E^(1/2 (-(b/m) + Sqrt[b^2 - 4 k m]/m) t)
      C[2] - ((E^(1/2 (-(b/m) - Sqrt[b^2 - 4 k m]/m) t) - E^(
       1/2 (-(b/m) + Sqrt[b^2 - 4 k m]/m) t)) HeavisideTheta[t])/Sqrt[
    b^2 - 4 k m] *)
```

> Also, this can be solved for `u[t]`:
>
> ```
> DSolveValue[m x''[t] + b x'[t] + k x[t] == u[t], x[t], t]
> ```

To [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) it you need to specify the constants and initial condition.

---

Let's say you have the initial condition in a form of $x(0) = x_0$ and $x'(0) = v$ and $u(t) = \sin t$ (and :

```
s = DSolveValue[{m x''[t] + b x'[t] + k x[t] == Sin[t], x[0] == x0, 
    x'[0] == v}, x[t], t];
Plot[Evaluate[
  s /. {m -> 2, b -> 1, k -> 1} /. {{x0 -> 0, v -> 1}, {x0 -> 0, 
     v -> 2}, {x0 -> 0, v -> 5}}], {t, 0, 10}, PlotTheme -> "Web"]
```

[image: dsolve solution]

Here I plot the solution (`s`) for a constants all equal to 1 and for a number of initial conditions. Check the [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) for `/.` understanding.

And plot of both displacement and velocity can be done with:

```
Plot[Evaluate[{s, D[s, t]} /. {m -> 2, b -> 1, k -> 1, x0 -> 0, 
    v -> 1}], {t, 0, 10}, PlotTheme -> "Web"]
```

Plot of `s`, which is a displacement, and [`D[s, t]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D.html), which is a velocity.

[image]

---

To analyse for over, under and critical dumping you need to assign $b$, $m$ and $k$ values, based on relation:

- $b^2 < 4 mk$ - underdamping;
- $b^2 > 4 mk$ - overdamping;
- $b^2 = 4 mk$ - critical damping.

To analyze this, it would be better to solve equation for particular values:

```
s[m_, b_, k_] := 
  DSolveValue[{m x''[t] + b x'[t] + k x[t] == Sin[t], x[0] == x0, 
    x'[0] == v}, x[t], t];

Plot[Evaluate[
  MapThread[s, {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 16, 2}, {1, 1, 1}}] /. {x0 -> 0, 
    v -> 1}], {t, 0, 10}, PlotTheme -> "Web"]
```

Where, blue - underdamping, orange - overdamping and yellow - critical.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the complete answer.

Comment: @Sam I have extended with plots of displacement for over-, under- and critical dumping.